# Нахождение наилучшей выборки

Tags: алгоритм, булева-алгебра

Писал калькулятор булевых функций на плюсах. Поставил задачу найти МДНФ и МКНФ методом Куайна.

В общем, застрял на импликантной матрице...
С созданием "ядра" для МДНФ все очевидно. Непонятен способ нахождения наилучшей выборки для полного покрытия членов СДНФ.

В силу огромного опыта в программировании за плечами (3 месяца), вообще не шарю насчет рекурсивных алгоритмов, динамического программирования или методов возврата(если хоть что-то из перечисленного уместно для данной задачи). Не хочется использовать банальную перетасовку всех возможных комбинаций.

Просьба заключается в предложении наиболее подходящего алгоритма для данной задачи и, если это возможно, его подробного описания. Буду благодарен за любой ответ!